# Why can't both Windows and Ubuntu recognize a filename with special characters?

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rm

I was trying to append to a text file in bash in WSL (using the `>>` operator). Unfortunately since I'm a beginner instead of appending to a file, a new file was made with the `>>` 'text' as the filename, and it seems like both Windows (GUI) and Ubuntu (`rm` command) cannot delete the file while it's in the directory (it's shown even when using the `dir` command).

- Windows GUI:

  [image: Directory In windows GUI]
- Windows error code:

  [image: Windows error code]
- Bash:

  ```
  root@DESKTOP-IA030GJ:/# cd home
  root@DESKTOP-IA030GJ:/home# dir
  English_Class  Finished_Projects  Keeping.txt  Random_Password_Generator_Project  \\n\\n\ -----Changes\   onion_project  pythonwork
  root@DESKTOP-IA030GJ:/home# ls --quoting-style=shell
   English_Class                      '\n\n -----Changes '
   Finished_Projects                   onion_project
   Keeping.txt                         pythonwork
   Random_Password_Generator_Project
  ```

Comment: Edit your post to add the output of `ls --quoting-style=shell`, please.

Comment: @muru Done , Thanks again for your time sir.

Comment: There, now you know what the filename actually looks like. Try `rm` with that filename.

Comment: @muru Problem Solved , Thanks for your time , Have a great day.

Answer (score 6):

This filename contains special characters because of how you originally (accidentally) piped data around.  Because of that we need to know the *exact* filename and use that in the `rm` command in quotes.

We know that your file is named exactly `\n\n -----Changes` .  So let's use that.  **Do not remove the single quotes from this command or it won't work.**

```
rm '\n\n -----Changes '
```

This should get rid of that file completely, without any subsequent issues.

Note that you could also have removed the file by using `*Changes*` as a pattern for removal, or add the `-i` flag with this as well to make it interactive to make sure the files you want to delete are in fact being deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your time sir, Problem solved .